# Passing ArrayList<NameValuePair> to ASyncTask and Update Values

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on a project where I am trying to implement an ASyncTask to post to a web server.

I have my class defined as follows:

```
public class PostToAPI extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, JSONObject> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener
```

I have my doInBackground method defined as follows:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... postData)
```

I am trying to create a new `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` which will include everything in postData plus some extra values but I keep getting an error.

Below is what I've tried

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... postData)
{
   List<NameValuePair> updatedPostData = new ArrayList<>();
   updatedPostData.addAll(postData);
updatedPostData.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Defines.PreferenceSettings.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                        settings.getString(Defines.PreferenceSettings.ACCESS_TOKEN, "")));
                updatedPostData.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Defines.PreferenceSettings.USER_ID,
                        String.valueOf(settings.getInt(Defines.PreferenceSettings.USER_ID, 0))));
}
```

I'm getting an error on the `updatedPostData.addAll(postData)`. The error is:

```
addAll (java.util.Collection? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>) in
List cannot be applied to (java.util.List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>[])
```

Now that looks to me like doInBackground is passing an array of List which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is only one element in `postData`, just add a subscript like this:

```
updatedPostData.addAll(postData[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your varargs parameter `List<NameValuePair>... postData` is an array of  `List<NameValuePair>`.

Try `protected JSONObject doInBackground(List<NameValuePair> postData)`.

Comment: This won't work since `AsyncTask` requires `doInBackground()` to take a varargs parameter.